# JButton.setBounds(x,y,w,h) doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleExample extends JFrame {

    public SimpleExample() {

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton jb = new JButton("TEST");
        jb.setBorderPainted(true);
        jb.setBounds(5, 5, 1, 1); ---> This line
        add(jb);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleExample ex = new SimpleExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just creating a simple button of a preferred size. The `setBounds` method doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your frame is under the control of a layout manager, it is making the decisions on how best to layout your components and is overriding the values you have specified using `setBounds`

Modern GUIs need to run (even on the same OS) in a variety of different graphical environments, including different DPI, screen sizes and font settings for example.

The layout manager makes it possible for you to worry (less) about these issues and it is highly recommended that you make use of them

Take a look at

- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

For more details

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you should not add the button directly to the `JFrame`. Instead, add a `JPanel` to the frame, set the panel's layout to `null`, and add the `JButton` to the `JPanel`.

Comment: `null` layouts are highlight unrecommended as they lead to more issues and problems then they solve. If you're after developing modern UI's that are capable of running on a variety of different graphical environments, then it is recommended you make use of appropriate layout managers. nb- Not the down voter, but a supporter