# JPanel dropdown menu cut off

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm practicing Java by creating a text analyzing program (word count, TF-IDF, etc).

I'm now constructing a small GUI to be displayed at the top of the frame. I want a dropdown menu, and I'm trying to create one using a `JPanel` and several `JButton` components. But to make the dropdown reusable, I've been trying to construct a class to manage it.

However, I encountered a problem: when I try to create the dropdown menu it's only visible in the upper left corner of the frame, and if I try to move it, it gets cut off or disappears completely.

I tried creating a simple method to do the same thing, but the problem remains the same. Here's the relevant code (ignore the processor and `State` stuff):

```
public class ExperimentState extends State {

    private JFrame frame;

    public ExperimentState(Processor processor) {
        super(processor);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        int width, height;
        //these variables are temporary, for testing
        width = 800;
        height = 640;

        //Set up the frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Test code
        String[] buttonNames = { "42", "Don't panic!", "Towel"};
        //                         x, y, width, height, button names
        JPanel panel = createPanel(0, 0, 100, 25, buttonNames);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);  
    }

    public JPanel createPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String[] names) {
        //Create and setup the panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[names.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(names[i]);
            button.setBounds(x, y + height*i, width, height); //each button has the size of the panel, and are placed on top of each other
            panel.add(button);
            buttons[i] = button;
        }
        buttons[0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height*names.length); //the panel extends to reveal all the buttons
            }   
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height); //the panel retracts
            }
        });

        return panel;   
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        frame.setVisible(false);    
    }
}
```

I thought there would be a problem with the mouse listener, since I don't really know how they work and thought they wouldn't be able to access the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` variables anytime they were called, but there was no problem.

The problem appears when I call `createPanel()` with something like `createPanel(50, 0, 100, 25, buttonNames)`.

Here, x is 50 instead of 0. When displayed, the panel is moved to the right, as it should be, but its buttons are now cut in half by some invisible line. If x = 100, it will go completely invisible.

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Never set location by yourself, use an appropriate layout manager.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.

But is this the core of the problem? If I manually create the same dropdown menu, there's no problem with positioning it wherever I want in the frame. There's only a problem when I use a method or class to do the job.

Comment: Yes I bet it is your problem There is a lot of such question everywhere on the web and the solution is always the same... Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481559/jbutton-setboundsx-y-w-h-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JButton.setBounds(x,y,w,h) doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481559/jbutton-setboundsx-y-w-h-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into it!

Comment: Look at your code, the panel has size (100,25), what do you think it will happens if button bounds is (100,x)? It will be outside. Bounds are relative to parent.

Comment: *"I want a dropdown menu"* - What's wrong with `JPopupMenu`?

Comment: *"(ignore the processor and `State` stuff)"* I'd more likely ignore the entire question. We don't need to ignore code when there is a [mcve]. Prepare and post an MCVE as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components inside a Container will only completely show (without a LayoutManager) if the bounds of these Components are completely inside it. By changing the x-coordinate from 0 to 50 you move the location of the Button. If you do not change its size or the size of your container your Button will be cut off.

The easiest way to fix this problem is to replace x and y in the location of your button with 0 and replace the 0‘s in the location of the Panel with x and y.

EDIT: Similar Problem here: [Components not showing in second JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046215/components-not-showing-in-second-jpanel)